# Total number of subgroups of a group

Tags: group-theory

> Is there a way to calculate the total number of subgroups of a group?

I can imagine that for example if $G=D_n$ is the dihedral group or $G=S_n$ the symmetric group then there exists a formula to calculate the total number of subgroups.

The reason why I started to think about this question is because I was trying to find all subgroups of $D_4$ (the square).

And I found some but I want to prove that I found all of them.

> So if the answer is no to the question above then I'd be equally happy
>   with a way of being sure that given a collection of subgroups to
>   determine that there cannot be more.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132675/general-bound-for-the-number-of-subgroups-of-a-finite-group), which basically says the answer is no. However, it also contains the nice fact that any subgroup is generated by at most $\log_2(|G|)$ elements, which does limit the search space somewhat.

For dihedral groups, you can use a much more elementary counting argument: either the group is cyclic (and these are easily counted) or it contains a reflection. If we call one such reflection $r$... can you finish from here?

Answer (score 0):

The total number of subroups $D_{n}$ are 
$$\tau(n)+\sigma(n)$$
Where $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of n and $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisors of $n$

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779351/prove-that-the-number-of-subgroups-in-d-n-tau-n-sigma-n).